# Path to .shp file

Tags: wpf, vb.net, path

I've got a Shapefile in my Project and i'm not able to get the relative path. I dont know whats the problem, maybe sb can help me. 
The name of Shapfile is: countries.shp.

Here are the project folders
[Project Folders](https://s16.postimg.org/8rkke5w8l/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

The term `shapefile` is quite common, but is misleading since the format consists of a collection of files with a common filename prefix, stored in the same directory. The three mandatory files have filename extensions **.shp**, **.shx**, and **.dbf**. The actual shapefile relates specifically to the .shp file, but alone is incomplete for distribution as the other supporting files are required. Legacy GIS software may expect that the filename prefix be limited to eight characters to conform to the DOS 8.3 filename convention, though modern software applications accept files with longer names.

- .shp — shape format; the feature geometry itself
- .shx — shape index format; a positional index of the feature geometry
  to allow seeking forwards and backwards quickly
- .dbf — attribute format; columnar attributes for each shape, in dBase
  IV format

I found following path to `Countries.shp` but your question needs to be updated and more specific.

```
<dxm:ShapefileDataAdapter FileUri="/ShowToolTips;component/Data/Shapefiles/Countries.shp"/>
```

Please note, normally you need GIS Software or your own code for reading .shp files. The [WPF Map Control (DevExpress)](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/Map/) is a very special Control Library and you may ask the support team of DevExpress.